# By what rule or property ((-3) mod 11) are comparable with (11 mod 8)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$(-3\mod{11})$ comparable with  $(8\mod{11})$

I want to understand on which algorithm these expressions are comparable.

Comment: How have you had mod defined?

Comment: @Arthur I would consider this an inappropriate edit. The fact that mathematicians consider mod to mean one things does not mean it cannot be used as an operator.

Comment: Can we change $(11 \bmod 8)$ to $(8 \bmod 11)$ in the title, so it matches the question?

Comment: I agree that $\bmod$ should remain a binary operator in the question, rather than the (more usual, in mathematics) notation $\pmod{11}$, precisely because the question hinges on what the binary operator means. In many computer programming environments, $-3\bmod11$ is _different_ from $8\bmod11$.

Comment: The title is different than the question.  -3 mid 11 ~ 8 mod 11 is straightforward (see some of the answers).  But -3 mod 11 ~ 11 mod 8 is ... possibly interesting in context and my have some interesting insights but isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

$\;-3\pmod{11}\;$ is the additive inverse of $\;3\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z/(11)\;$ , so all you have to do is answer: what number added $\;\pmod{11}\;$ to $\;3\;$ equals $\;0\pmod{11}\;?$

The answer(s): $\;8,19,30,...\;$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what definition you have of congruence classes, so I will give you one interpretation which might conflict with yours in spirit, but I guarantee that the concrete mathematical results are the same regardless.

In a way, $-3 \mod{11}$ stands for the set containing *every number* $i$ for which there is an integer $n$ such that
$$
i = -3 + 11n
$$
Clearly, $8$ is in there, using $n = 1$:
$$
8 = -3 + 11\cdot 1
$$
and so is for instance $19$, since $19 = -3 + 11\cdot 2$, and $$16\,409 = -3 + 11\cdot 1492$$
In more systematic notation, you may write the set as
$$
\{\ldots, -25, -14, -3, 8, 19, 30, \ldots\}
$$
If you do the same thing with $8 \mod{11}$, you see that you end up with exactly the same set, except that the $n$ you multiply by $11$ to show that some number is a part of the set is different. For instance, to show that $8$ is in there, you need $0$ instead of $1$:
$$
8 = 8 + 11\cdot 0
$$
and $16\,409$ uses $n = 1491$ instead. But this doesn't matter, because it isn't exxplicitly important *which* $n$ we use, only what numbers we can reach using all the different possible $n$.